# Mongoose: does a custom _id need to be declared as an index and be unique

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Here is the common way to define a collection structure with Mongoose :

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    username: String,
    ...
});
```

And Now I want _id field declared as Number type :

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    username: String,
    ...
});
```

The problem is, do I need to declare more infomation about _id ? Such as :

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type: Number, required: true, index: {unique: true}},
    username: String,
    ...
});
```

I am not sure whether MongoDB would do it automatically.

if you know the answer, could you leave a comment below ? Thank you!

Comment: When you create a new model mongoose declares **'_id'** as ObjectId, but there is another field called **'id'** (without underline), so this variable/field cast to String. Yes, this is not a number, but you can use it easier that ObjectId. 

As for **'_id'**, you are absolutely right as you may set it manually like `'_id: Number'`. This option is allowed in **Mongoose 3.6+**.

Answer (score 6):

Well, after some practice,  I realized that, MongoDB would set _id as PRIMARY KEY (NOT NULL + UNIQUE INDEX) automatically. So, just type:

```
_id: Number,
...
```