# Mongoose uuid insted ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to use uuid string instead ObjectId in _id field.

models/user.js

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {type: String, default: uuid.v4},
    nick: {type: String, unique : true, default: ""},
    email: {type: String, default: ""},
    pass: {type: String, default: ""},
    admin: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    modified: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

Unique is necessary?

```
_id: {type: String, unique : true, default: uuid.v4},
```

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900863/mongoose-does-a-custom-id-need-to-be-declared-as-an-index-and-be-unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UUID's are by definition unique, so you don't necessarily need to define the _id to be unique in your model.

Comment: But you'd still want to mark it as such to guard against programmer error.

Comment: By wiki "While the probability that a UUID will be duplicated is not zero, it is so close to zero as to be negligible"  but mongodb set _id as PRIMARY KEY (NOT NULL + UNIQUE INDEX) automatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900863/mongoose-does-a-custom-id-need-to-be-declared-as-an-index-and-be-unique sorry for dup question